# Enumeration warning

Tags: java, eclipse, enumeration, rxtx

I want to execute with Eclipse the example code provided from [this RxTx web site](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Discovering_comm_ports)
 :

```
import gnu.io.*;
public class SerialPortLister {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        listPorts();
    }
    private static void listPorts()
    {
        java.util.Enumeration<CommPortIdentifier> portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();  // this line has the warning
        while ( portEnum.hasMoreElements() ) 
        {
            CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = portEnum.nextElement();
            System.out.println(portIdentifier.getName()  +  " - " +  getPortTypeName(portIdentifier.getPortType()) );
        }        
    }
    private static String getPortTypeName ( int portType )
    {
        switch ( portType )
        {
            case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_I2C:
                return "I2C";
            case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_PARALLEL:
                return "Parallel";
            case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_RAW:
                return "Raw";
            case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_RS485:
                return "RS485";
            case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL:
                return "Serial";
            default:
                return "unknown type";
        }
    }
}
```

On line 13 there is a warning : `Type safety: The expression of type Enumeration needs unchecked conversion to conform to Enumeration<CommPortIdentifier>`

What does this warning mean and how to solve it ?

Comment: I guess you should also show the code for getPortIdentifiers

Comment: Please indicate the line no here, by inserting the comment there.

Comment: getPortIdentifiers() is a static method

Comment: I included the comment just at the end of the first line code of the `private static void listPorts()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know code of getPortIdentifiers method, but in the current situation:

- The solution is to add the following annotation in front of the method for which the warning is reported: @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
- You can also cast the type to be unknown type. Example:  Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

Answer (score 8):

Elaborating more on the second bullet point from Vladislav Bauer, you could initialize the portEnum like:

```
Enumeration<?> portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
```

And then inside of the while structure you can do the casting of each element to the type you need, in this case CommPortIdentifier:

```
 CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum.nextElement();
```

Casting each element will make the warning disappear. But we have to be careful and make sure that portEnum always contains elements of type CommPortIdentifier as we expect.